# Problem receiving data from Server Component (NextJS)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

On my client component, I call getBenchmarksByUser() to fetch the data I need:

```js
export default function BenchmarkBrowser({uid}) {
    
    console.log("client uid:", {uid})
    
    // Watch the state of our Benchmarks
    const [benchmarks, setBenchmarks] = useState();
    
    // Send the server a request for our Benchmarks
    
    useEffect(() => {

        console.log("BenchmarkBrowser component is rendered.");

        getBenchmarksByUser(uid).then((res) => {

            console.log("benchmarks received by client", res);
            setBenchmarks(res);

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error!", err);
        });
    }, [uid]);

    return (
        <>
        <h1>benchmark browser...</h1>
        </>
    );
}
```

On the server component, it queries Firestore and returns the docs in question:

```js
'use server'
import { db } from "@/lib/firebase";
import { query, getDocs, collection, orderBy, limit } from "firebase/firestore";

export async function getBenchmarksByUser(uid) {

    console.log("server received uid:", uid);
    
    const benchmarksQuery = query(
        collection(db, 'users/' + uid + '/benchmarks'), 
        orderBy('created'), 
        limit(5)
    );
    
    await getDocs(benchmarksQuery).then((res) => {
        console.log("server snapshot docs length", res.docs.length)
        return res.docs;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("ERROR",err);
        return null;
    })
    
}
```

What's bizarre to me is that I KNOW the data has been fetched properly because I can see my console outputs [in the server console (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YEVp.png)

But when it's returned to the client component, it's undefined! [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbdBu.png)

What's going on here? Why is my data suddenly undefined?

Comment: Even if I force a simple return in getBenchmarksByUser like `return "test"`, the client component still receives `undefined` ... does anyone know why?

Comment: is `uid` defined? Maybe the prop is not passed down correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem was, in the Server Component I was returning the result of a promise in `.then()`

Storing the result of the promise in a `const`, and  returning it in the next line, fixed the issue.

NOTE: This code *works*, but returns a warning in the server console, because I haven't converted the data to a simple object before returning it to the Client Component. (see [Passing props from Server to Client Components (Serialization)](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#passing-props-from-server-to-client-components-serialization))

```js
'use server'
import 'server-only'

import { db, docToJSON } from "@/lib/firebase";
import { query, getDocs, collection, orderBy, limit } from "firebase/firestore";

export default async function getBenchmarksByUser(uid) {

    console.log("server received uid:", uid);
    
    const benchmarksQuery = query(
        collection(db, 'users/' + uid + '/benchmarks'), 
        orderBy('created'), 
        limit(5)
    );
    
    const snapshot = await getDocs(benchmarksQuery);
    
    console.log("returning doc count:", snapshot.docs.length);

    return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because your `getBenchmarksByUser` is async, but you do not `await` for it.

Try

```
useEffect(() => {

    if (!uid) return;
    const getData = async () => {
        const res = await getBenchmarksByUser(uid);
        setBenchmarks(res);
    } 
    getData();
        
}, [uid]);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result where `res` is `undefined`